# How can I enable CSS and JavaScript syntax validation in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, ubuntu-12.04, validation, css

I use Eclipse Kepler and can't work out how to make Eclipse highlight e.g. undefined function in JavaScript or wrong attribute in CSS.

Comment: Try Aptana, as stand-alone or plugin, it has better validation plugins.

Comment: I think I might get used to Aptana. Thanks ;)